# Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'AppDelegate'

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild

I receive this error

```
Property implementation must have its declaration in interface "AppDelegate"
```

When I declare

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, viewController;
@synthesize token;
```

I'm using Xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you need to go to your `AppDelegate.h` file, and add a declaration for `token`. Let's say it's `NSString*`; then you should add the following line to your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *token;
```

Substitute `NSString*` for the correct type of your `token` property. More information about properties can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Comment: the Token it is a Token for Push Notification, could you suggest me the correct type? Many thanks

Comment: I think it's `NSData*`, but I am not 100% certain of that.

Comment: it work many thanks I use this as property @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* token;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't set **widow**, **viewController** or **token** as properties in your .h file.

Did you type `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *token;`